# Regarding EXEC, EXECUTE, SP_EXECUTE and SP_EXECUTESQL

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please differentiate between EXEC, EXECUTE, SP_EXECUTE and SP_EXECUTESQL in Micorsoft SQL?

Comment: What has the research you have already done told you, and what didn't you understand?

Comment: I am talking about any live examples. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_execute` is depreciated and is used by OLEDB.

`EXEC` and `EXECUTE` are the same thing, one is just shorthand

`Sp_executesql` is similar to `EXEC` / `EXECUTE` however it accepts parameters to ensure dynamic queries are not affected by SQL injection. `sp_executesql` also caches the execution plan in a similar way to a stored procedure so you don't have the cost of plan compilation on every run

I would use `sp_executesql` in most if not all cases